# Find out which AsyncTask is mentioned in the crash log

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Is there any way to find out which AsyncTask object is the AsyncTask mentioned in the below "Crahlytics" log? :-

```
AsyncTask #2
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1038)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: `AsyncTask #2` ?

Comment: Yes, AsyncTask #2 how to find out the name of the asynctask object?

Comment: Do you think we know the names? Do you think we know how many async tasks you have? Do you think we know your code?

Comment: I dont think that , but I think you might know a technique to figure out.

Comment: Just place a lot of Log.d() statements in your code. And why do you have that log? It seems that a lot is missing? It looks as if you removed the error/exception.

Comment: @greenapps These logs are from Crashlytics, not from logcat.

Comment: You could mention that info at the start of your post.